Forcing volta brackets to be closed (v2.24.3)
This is actually a repeat of a 20 year old question that I never found an answer to:
I'm trying to get something like this:
          |--------------||--------------||-------------- 
|: Notes1 | Alternative1 :| Alternative2 || Alternative3 |. Notes2...

The problem I'm facing is that the right side of the second volta bracket is open as soon as I'm changing the bar line after the second alternative to "|.|" using the \bar command.
Here is my test case:
\version "2.24.0"

voltaToVerse = \markup { 2. \text \italic { to verse } }
voltaFine = \markup { \text \bold { Final. } }

\relative {
  f''4 g a b
  \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "1."))
  c1 
  \bar ":|."

  \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta voltaToVerse))
  c1 
  \bar "|.|"
  
  \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta voltaFine))
  c1
  \bar ".."
  \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
}

Here's what I get:

Any hints how to force the volta brackets to be closed on the 2nd ending are welcome.

Use
\allowVoltaHook "|.|"

on toplevel to set voltas to hook down at this bar line glyph. Alternatively we might do something like
\once\override Score.VoltaBracket.before-line-breaking =
#(lambda (grob)
   (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'edge-height '(2 . 2)))

to selectively hook down specific Volta brackets. Here is a MWE showing both options in action:
\allowVoltaHook "|.|"

\repeat volta 4 {
  \alternative {
    { 1 \bar "||" }
    { 1 \bar "|.|" }
    {
      \once\override Score.VoltaBracket.before-line-breaking =
      #(lambda (grob)
         (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'edge-height '(2 . 2)))
      1 \bar "."
    }
    { 1 \bar ".." }
  }
}

